# How to generate a unique code

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I connect up to my DB and a user submit their email address. This is stored in the DB. This is something I have grabbed from a turorial.

I'd like a user-unique code generated through JS on document load..
Format should be 6 digits in length and only using only A-Z and 0-9. ie: F4DRB6

Once that is done I'd need to store that unique code for that user in the DB.
The generator should check if the unique code exists in the DB, to ensure it is actually unique.

The trouble I am having is; I don't know how to create the unique code in the above format, checking if it is unique from the DB, and then storing it in the DB corresponding to that user. I'd assume another column to match the row somehow?

Thanks!

**EDIT: I have attempted with this.. if there is any error please do point it out. Thanks**

```
function genRandomString() {
    $length = 5;
    $characters = '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $string = '';    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}

do {
  $random_string = $this->genRandomString();
} while (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT referralcode FROM ".coming_soon_emails." WHERE rand_string='{$random_string}'")));
$q = "INSERT INTO ".coming_soon_emails." SET referralcode='{$random_string}'";
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

Comment: do you want your generated code to be in sequence (00000A,00000B,00000C...), or randomized( 123AE3, ABCD34,...)?

Comment: What do you want to use that code for?

Comment: @deceze: The code will be given to the user for a referral url. ie: http://www.example.com/F4DRB6

Comment: I think you'd be better off letting the database generate your unique value, that's where the uniqueness is enforced so the generation logic should be as close to the database as possible. You'll also have fewer concurrency problems that way. You could get away with an auto-increment column and a bit of hashing.

Comment: @mu is too short: PERFECT! Makes more sense! How can I go about doing that? Then displaying the unique URL as grabbed from the DB?

Comment: actually, you dont need to generate your unique code upfront, you should only do it after the new user has entered all information and passed through validation. Then you can get a new key and store it along with the new user info. So the key is not exposed to user and you need not to worry about unique URL.

Comment: @Winfred: Makes sense too. The user is given the URL+UNIQUE_CODE to then share as a referral for me to track later. With your comment above, how do I create a new (unique) key (checked against db) and stored by the user in the same row, different column.

Answer (score 3):

why you need that to be created in client-side? Why can't you just create the code when the client submits the "final" form?

You can create this code [randomly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and you put the column that handles the code as `unique`. If you get a violation error, you generate another and try again.

Well, this is one of the ways to do...

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll add a function once the form is submitting. The issue I am having is 1) generating the code in the example I have shown with mixed A-Z and 0-9, and then storing that in the DB next to the submitted email address - in the same row.

Comment: [This](http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-random-string-with-numbers-and-letters/) should do the trick for ya

Answer (score 0):

In a causal way, a simple walk-through would be:

write a **function/SP** in mysql :

First, generate a random code, as AbiusX said, depends on your user pool size, the new code is probably rarely used.

This will generate one Hex character for you and should get you started.

> SELECT conv(FLOOR((RAND() * 16)),10,16);

Then you will need to check if this code has been used already.
`

> SELECT * FROM usertable where code =
>   generatedcode

if so, generate a new one.

In a more robust setting, I always pre-generate the unique codes, and store them in a table "unused code" etc, so I can just grab any code off there and ensure it is unique and not used.

Comment: I've updated my question with code - if that works, great, otherwise happy to go with yours :)

Answer (score -1):

Its simple math,
6^36 is large enough that creating a random id is mostly unique.

If you wanna be 100% sure use AJAX to check the generated ID in database and recreate if existing.